# LINQ to Entity Error on Inserting Records Because of Identity Field

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, identity

So basically, i'm trying to insert a record to my table using LINQ to Entity.

```
        using (MyEntities container = new MyEntities())
        {
             container.MyTable.AddObject(record);
             container.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Now my problem is this: The table i'm inserting into has a column ID which is PK and is an Identity field. In my model, I made sure that I set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` property of the column to `IDENTITY`. However, when I do run my code, it's still giving me the error message:

```
"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'MyTable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."
```

Am I missing any other property for my model thatI need to update?

Thanks!

Comment: show your mapping code

Comment: Is this EF code-first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811931/ef-code-first-cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-mytab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be caused because you explicitly gave an ID to your object AND you set the `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `IDENTITY`, which auto-generate the ID field (which is Primary Key).
Did you check if you assign a value for the ID field of your object named `record`? If so, try to remove the assignement of the ID field, it will be assigned on Insert by the model.

**EDIT** : Maybe that's because the database know that this field should autoincremented, but not EF. 
Open the edmx file and in the store schema definition language (SSDL) area, add the attribute `StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"`.Your entity type definition will look more or less like this:

```
<EntityType Name="INVOICE">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="CODE" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="CODE" Type="varchar" Nullable="false"
              MaxLength="10" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity"/>         
 </EntityType>
```

This should work but if you update your model, these changes will be lost, and you'll have to do it again.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't give a value to the ID field on my code. But after doing some debugging, it seems like it's automatically getting 0 as its value. Any thoughts on why that is? Thanks so much!

Comment: You should look at the **EDIT** part of my answer, I added some elements you should try. I think this is a probleme that might have occured !

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I updated my Model thru the Model Browser and made sure that `StoreGeneratedPattern` is set to Identity. I don't know why that XML didn't pick it up! Thanks again!